# Algolia for React Native: refine() method

Tags: react-native, algolia, react-instantsearch

I wish to use Algolia to setup InstantSearch in my React Native project. I am using [this tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/) to learn the basics.

It appears in their `RefinementList` and `InfiniteHits` components there is a parameter: `refine`. This parameter seems to play a key role in the functionality of this tutorial's app.

Where can I get an example of how this `refine()` method would look like?
Please help me with some resources. An explanation of this `refine()` method would also help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please look into it [Link](http://blog.logicwind.com/search-with-algolia/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a typo in the documentation at the time of this writing (for which I opened a pull request), and the name of the actual prop is `refineNext`.

The documented `InfiniteHits` example from the React Native guide uses a connector, which is a lower-level abstraction allowing users to fully control the UI. This is what allows you to use React Native code for the UI while having access to the `InfiniteHits` data and logic. You can read more about the [`connectInfiniteHits` connector](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/infinite-hits/react/#connector) in the documentation.

The provided [`refineNext`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/infinite-hits/react/#connector-param-provided-refinenext) function lets you load more results. It doesn't take any arguments, all you need to do is call it whenever you want to load more results from Algolia. In the example, it's being used in the [`onEndReached`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached) callback of React Native's `FlatList` component, whenever the `hasMore` provided prop is `true`. This allows loading more results once when the scroll position gets within [`onEndReachedThreshold`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold) of the rendered content.